# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/I0Itec/zkclient/serialize/ZkSerializer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-karaf

I am posting solution to this issue in karaf.

Just go to .m2/repository/org/apache/camel/karaf/2.14.1/apache-camel-2.14.1-features.xml.

And lookup for camel-kafka feature. And add zkclient bundle and upgrade the zookeeper bundle.

```
<bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.8</bundle>
<bundle dependency='true'>wrap:mvn:com.101tec/zkclient/0.8</bundle>
```

This will resolve the issue.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Comment: I propose to reformat this to the usual stack overflow style. Use the question to only describe the problem and how to reproduce it and then post your own answer to it.